# Python turtle graph

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics

Can anyone help me clean up my graph. When I plot the y-xis, I want the integers rounded to the nearest hundredth. Also, under each bar I need to label 'a' - 'z': 26 bars total:

```
def letterFreqPlot(freqList):    
    border = 5
    t = turtle.Turtle()
    t.pensize(3)
    screen = t.getscreen()
    maxheight = max(freqList)
    numbers = len(freqList)
    screen.setworldcoordinates(0-border,-.05,numbers+1,maxheight+.1)
    t.goto(0,0)
    t.hideturtle()
    t.speed(0)
    t.lt(90)
    t.fd(maxheight)
    t.fd(-maxheight)
    t.right(90)
    for item in freqList:
        t.fillcolor("blue")
        t.begin_fill()
        for dist in [1, item, 1, item]:           
            t.fd(dist)
            t.lt(90)
        t.fd(1)
        t.end_fill()
    t.goto(0,0)
    t.lt(90)
    for i in freqList:
        t.fd(i)
        t.lt(90)
        t.fd(3)
        t.write(float(i))
        t.fd(-3)
        t.rt(90)
        t.fd(-i)
    print('Click to exit')
    screen.exitonclick()
freqList = letterFreq(words)
letterFreqPlot(freqList)
```

freqList:

> [0.09090909090909091, 0.0, 0.0, 0.09090909090909091, 0.18181818181818182, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.045454545454545456, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.045454545454545456, 0.045454545454545456, 0.045454545454545456, 0.045454545454545456, 0.18181818181818182, 0.045454545454545456,  0.09090909090909091, 0.045454545454545456, 0.0, 0.045454545454545456, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]

Comment: Rounding integers to the nearest hundredth is unclear.  Did you mean floats?

Comment: I think your frequency list should be raw counts.  If you round .045 to either .04 or .05, is will no longer be exactly half of .09, as it is now.  If you need help with the turtle.write method after reading the doc, look at the turtledemo examples that write text, such as the tick() function in the clock demo.

Answer (score 1):

Below is my attempt to add the features you wanted to the graph as well as optimize the drawing code a bit and add a feature:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

BORDER = 5
FONT = ("Arial", 12, "normal")
FLOAT_FORMAT = "0.2f"
PENSIZE = 3

def letterFrequency(string):
    counter = dict()

    length = ord('z') - ord('a') + 1

    for ordinal in range(length):
        counter[chr(ordinal + ord('a'))] = 0

    count = 0

    for character in string:
        if character.isalpha():
            counter[character] += 1
            count += 1

    return [counter[key] / count for key in sorted(counter)]


def letterFreqPlot(turtle, canvas, string):

    turtle.pensize(PENSIZE)

    frequencyList = letterFrequency(string)

    maxheight = max(frequencyList)
    numbers = len(frequencyList)

    canvas.setworldcoordinates(-BORDER, -.05, numbers + 1, maxheight + 0.1)

    turtle.hideturtle()

    for frequency in sorted(set(frequencyList)):
        turtle.penup()
        turtle.home()
        turtle.lt(90)
        turtle.pendown()
        turtle.forward(frequency)
        turtle.left(90)
        turtle.forward(3)
        turtle.write(format(frequency, FLOAT_FORMAT), font=FONT)

    turtle.penup()
    turtle.home()
    turtle.sety(-0.0125)

    for i, frequency in enumerate(frequencyList):
        turtle.forward(0.5)
        turtle.write(chr(ord('a') + i), font=FONT)
        turtle.forward(0.5)

    turtle.home()
    turtle.goto(len(frequencyList) / 2, -0.025)
    turtle.write(string, align="center", font=FONT)

    turtle.home()
    turtle.fillcolor("blue")
    turtle.pendown()

    for frequency in frequencyList:
        if frequency > 0.0:
            turtle.begin_fill()
            for distance in [1, frequency] * 2:
                turtle.forward(distance)
                turtle.left(90)
            turtle.end_fill()
        turtle.forward(1)


yertle = Turtle()
yertle.speed("fastest")

screen = Screen()

letterFreqPlot(yertle, screen, "an opportunity to teach is an opportunity to learn")

screen.exitonclick()
```

Rather than having the drawing code backtrack so much, I made use of `turtle.home()` to reset the starting point and orientation.  I also added a simple minded emulation of your `letterFrequency()` code for fun.  I gathered many of the constants together but there's more to do along those lines.

[image]

BTW, yours is one of the best examples of `setworldcoordinates()` I've seen.